# How can I create a new tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript.
Can anyone tell me why my code shown below is not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- links.html by Bill Weinman http://bw.org/contact/ -->

<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <title>
        HTML Hyperlinks
    </title>        
</head>
<body>


<div id = "123">
<p id = "main">
    Here is a link to <a name = "hyper" href="http://yahoo.com/">page</a>.
    The text around the link is not part of the link. 
</p>
<script>


        var newTag = document.createElement("ul");
        var existingElement = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        existingElemen[0].appendChild ( newTag );
        var newLiTag =  document.createElement("li");
        newTag.appendChild (newLiTag);
        var textNode = document.createTextNode("here is the first unOrderedList");
        newLiTag.appendChild (textNode);

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Close the elements before the script tag, and you have typos.

Comment: existingElemen[0].appendChild ( newTag ); lacking a 't' at existingElemen[0]

Comment: Thanks I feel so dump now !!!

Comment: In the future: (a) open your JavaScript console to see errors while developing, and (b) when posting a question, please don't just include code (which is great), but also say what you expect to happen, and what is happening instead.

Comment: @Phrogz : there is no future :( I have so many negative votes that I cann't post any question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in your code:

```
existingElemen[0].appendChild ( newTag );
```

should be...

```
existingElement[0].appendChild( newTag );
```

One minor but related note... if you are building up a large list of DOM elements that you are adding to the page you likely want to build the set of elements in JavaScript first (e.g. 1 `<ul>` with 250 `<li>` elements inside it) and *then* add it to the page.  This lets the browser trigger 1 layout update vs. 251 separate layout updates. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Typo:

```
existingElemen[0].appendChild ( newTag );
```

Should be:

```
existingElement[0].appendChild( newTag );
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/c3REN/